# How to manually ack messages in RabbitMQ?

Tags: php, rabbitmq, queue, consumer, php-amqplib

I need to know how to manually ack the messages on the queue direct from the Consumer I created and to set a retry strategy of 5 times, each attemp increasing the time like second try 5min, third try, 10min after second try failed, fourth 15min...

I'm kinda lost in the Rabbit documentation, I learned a bit of the concept but the practical use is still a mistery to me...

I'm using Symfony 6.1 and my old_sound_rabbit_mq.yaml looks like this:

```
old_sound_rabbit_mq:
    connections:
        default:
            host: '%rabbitmqHost%'
            port: '%rabbitmqPort%'
            user: '%rabbitmqUser%'
            password: '%rabbitmqPassword%'
            vhost: '%rabbitmqVhost%'
    consumers:
        upload_file:
            connection: default
            exchange_options: { name: 'upload_file_exchange', type: direct, durable: true, auto_delete: false }
            queue_options: { name: 'upload_file_queue', durable: true, auto_delete: false, arguments: { 'x-max-priority': [ 'I', 20 ] } }
            callback: App\Consumer\UploadFileConsumer
            qos_options: { prefetch_size: 0, prefetch_count: 1, global: false }
```

This is my consumer:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Consumer;

use OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\ConsumerInterface;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;

class UploadFileConsumer implements ConsumerInterface
{
    public function execute(AMQPMessage $msg): void
    {
        try {
            // do something with $msg, if all is good then ack the msg and remove from queue
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // keep message in queue, don't ack it, keep it in queue retry 5 times then stop consumer if no success
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

AMQPMessage provides both `ack()` and `nack()` methods for this purpose.

https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/blob/master/PhpAmqpLib/Message/AMQPMessage.php#L98-L128

So likely what you want is:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Consumer;

use OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\ConsumerInterface;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;

class UploadFileConsumer implements ConsumerInterface
{
    public function execute(AMQPMessage $msg): void
    {
        try {
            // do something with $msg
            $msg->ack();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // keep message in queue, don't ack it, keep it in queue retry
            $msg->nack(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Though I'm not familiar with a way to limit the number of times a message is re-queued without modifying the headers/payload and re-queueing it as a new message. Alternatively, you can set a TTL value and messages will eventually time out of the queue. You can also create a dead-letter exchange if you want to inspect nack'ed/expired messages. [just make sure to clean it out, otherwise you'll have new problems]

If I had to kludge in a "re-queue X times" I'd suggest a cache with a built-in TTL like Redis, the key is the message ID, and the value is the number of retries.

**Edit:**

Spitballing some workflows for "Task A must complete before Task B can begin", in order of decreasing preference:

- If Tasks A and B can never happen without each other, then consolidate Task A and Task B into a single task, as they are not independent.
- If Task B cannot happen without A, have B invoke A in synchronous/RPC fashion.
- Create new async Task C that calls A and B in synchronous/RPC fashion.
- Task A ends with submitting Task B to the queue. [this still has the smell of "A and B" are actually a single work unit]
- Track task status externally [eg: in a cache like Redis] and have Task B nack/requeue if Task A is not yet completed.

and always beware of "infinite requeue" if your queue does not have a defined TTL, as messages will continue to build up, and your consumers will be working constantly on tasks that may never be completed successfully.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer Sammitch. What I want is that the message never leaves the queue until its successfully processed by the consumer. The context of the task passed to me is that the messages in this queue have a sequence and if let's say message #2 goes before #1 things break! so #1 must go, eventually! otherwise queue should keep stopped.

Comment: Honestly, if Task A _must_ complete before Task B they should either be consolidated as a single task, or the completion of Task A includes queuing Task B. Alternatively, you could once again track task status externally and have Task B re-queue itself until Task A is tracked as completing successfully. Regardless, you definitely don't want to just infinitely re-queue failed messages, otherwise you'll wind up with a growing queue of bad messages, and constantly-spinning consumers.

Comment: I like the task queueing the next task idea, however I still have the problem that my message get consumed when I throw a Exception and in the Exception I do $msg->nack() : /

Comment: You need `$msg->nack(true)` to have the message re-queued. I've also expanded and better summarized my ideas in an edit to the post.

Comment: I'm reading your edit, basically the tasks are just messages with a file name and the consumer will attemp to upload to a remote SFTP, if succes, message can be dropped from queue and go for the next, otherwise keep trying to consume (and execute the callback which attemp to upload the file)

Comment: yes! nack(true) worked! However...the consumers "quits"...I wanted him to keep running listening (and retrying to proccess the last message